# Shopify Store Set-up

Tags: json, csv, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I want to setup a new Shopify store and list similar products from a couple of websites whose product list I scraped in JSON format. Will I be able to setup the store using this JSON data or do I need to convert it into CSV file or something else to proceed?

I have details like:

1. Name
2. Price
3. Product description
4. Product images URL.

The total quantity of products are > 100 000. How should I proceed? Will a JSON file be enough or do I need a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it to CSV. Shopify only allows importing products through CSV.

[image: Importing product to Shopify]

You can write a script to convert your JSON data to CSV, or use an online tool like [ConvertCSV](https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm) (assuming it can handle a JSON file with over 100,000 products defined).

You might not be able to add all 100,000 products at once though, unless you are on Shopify Plus.

> Shopify limits you to only being able to upload or create 1,000 new products or product variants every 24 hours after you exceed 50,000 products or variants in the store. See this [answer](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/maximum-number-of-products/m-p/1371894/highlight/true#M69902) on the Shopify Forums.